# How to move master and origin to detached head in git?

Tags: git, gitahead

I'm using GitAhead:

I had an infinite loop created 3 commits before the last one. So I *checked out* the working commit 525bd69, and then I *checked out*  individual changes in the code in the following commits (d15, 06 and d33) that wouldn't break the application.

Now I have a detached head that I want it to be my main branch with master, origin/HEAD and origin/master. I will be committing and pushing on this branch. I don't want to merge the detached head with d33 because that would mean using changes that I don't want from previous commits d33 into b35, I just want to carry on committing and pushing from b35.

[image: This is how the branches show]

I tried pushing the detached head but It won't let me. I tried merging d33 with b35 but it will introduce unwanted changes. I want the repository how it is at b35
I have managed to turn Detached head into a new branch. I now want to move origin/head and origin/master into that new branch.

Comment: Use `git revert` to fix a wrong commit. You don't travel back in time to prevent the commit before it ever happened.

Comment: Thank you, how can I fix my current situation now ?

Comment: Throw your changes away. Go to a clean and non-detached state with `git checkout master`, run `git revert` to undo the offending commit.

Comment: `git reset --hard b35` followed by `git push -f`

Comment: In the end I found what the reason for the infinite loop was, merged, fixed and pulled. Thank you for your input the issue was doing stuff wrong from the start